# 'Autoclicker' is namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am trying to make autoclicker but i get this error

[image of program.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7dHe.png)

my whole Autoclicker.cs file -> https://controlc.com/16cd5eb4

now i got new error.

Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Autoclicker.Autoclicker' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUcGj.png

Comment: AutoClicker is your project namespace so you must change to AutoClicker.AutoCliker()

Comment: Do you have any `Autoclicker` class that acts as an application context in your project? Looks like you are trying to just use the namespace declared on top of your code

Comment: You didn't save Autoclicker.cs. Maybe VS just isn't aware of it, because you didn't save it. Also, please share the code of Autoclicker.cs to verify that it is actually a class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there is a class named `AutoClicker`  under project `AutoClicker` (default namespace). In this case, you need to provide the fully qualified name of the class `AutoClicker`. It means combination between namespace and class name.

```cs
namespace AutoClicker
{
    internal class Client
    {
        private void TestMethod()
        {
            var autoClicker = new AutoClicker.AutoClicker();
        }
    }
}
```

AutoClicker.cs

```cs
namespace AutoClicker
{
    public class AutoClicker
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late, but I did not see any answers that addressed the actual issues. I will go ahead and post an answer for any future searchers landing on this question.

In your original "image of program.cs file" you have a closing curly bracket on line number 10 (it's still present on line 16 of the edited program.cs file as well) - this puts your main method outside of the Autoclicker namespace.

Once you have corrected that, your Autoclicker.cs class is declared in a separate namespace:

```
namespace autoclicker
```

Namespaces are case sensitive, so you will need to fix that as well - or you will have to qualify your instance as:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new autoclicker.Autoclicker());
    }
```

(note: qualifying the instance will only work if the Autoclicker.cs class namespace and the Autoclicker.Designer.cs class namespace match as described below)

The current error message you are getting is due to the class declared in the Autoclicker.cs file is actually named Combat:

```
public partial class Combat : Form
```

Either change that name to Autoclicker or update your Autoclicker.Designer.cs file class name to match:

Autoclicker.cs:

```
public partial class Autoclicker : Form
```

Autoclicker.Designer.cs:

```
partial class Autoclicker
```

-OR-

Autoclicker.cs:

```
public partial class Combat : Form
```

Autoclicker.Designer.cs:

```
partial class Combat
```

If these two class names are different AND/OR the namespaces they are contained in are different, the partial class feature will not auto combine them into one class - that is why you are getting the current error message.